# Does /proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first work?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I learned that setting a non-zero value in `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first` will force the child process to run before the parent. However, I don't think it seems to be working. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pid_t child_pid;

  switch(child_pid = fork())
    {
    case 0:
      printf("In Child\n");
      exit(0);

    case -1:
      printf("Could not fork()\n");

    default:
      printf("In parent\n");

    }
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get is always:

```
In parent
In Child
```

Am I expecting something wrong here?

PS: I am just experimenting to see if it works, so please refrain from suggesting other synchronization mechanisms or why this is a bad idea, etc.

Comment: Did you go through this: http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/child-runs-first.html

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Thanks for the link. yes I read most of the things there in Michael Kerrisk's book as well. But he suggested that setting the value in the above file "gurantees" that the child will run first, Or may be I read wrong.

Comment: but the link says that they are removing the support for this from kernel version 2.6 and I could not find a newer post where they said to have added the support again. So may be by this way it is not possible, but I am not a authority on this matter..:)

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam perhaps, i will need to dig deeper unless someone can confirm. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Using the following commands on a Raspberry Pi Zero w/ Raspbian:
$ sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first
$ ./fork_whos_on_first 10000 > fork.txt
$ ./fork_whos_on_first.count.awk fork.txt
I get the following numbers (vs. 100%, 100% for "0"):
child      21   0.21%
parent   9979  99.79%

Comment: Here's an email from Linus Torvalds https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/child-runs-first.html explaining some trade-offs and stating that there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 8):

From what I can make out, the place where the `sched_child_runs_first` feature is implemented is in the `task_fork_fair` function, the source for which you can see [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.8/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5733).

The key part of that function looks like this:

```
if (curr)
        se->vruntime = curr->vruntime;
place_entity(cfs_rq, se, 1);

if (sysctl_sched_child_runs_first && curr && entity_before(curr, se)) {
        swap(curr->vruntime, se->vruntime);
        resched_task(rq->curr);
}
```

*se* is the new scheduling entity and *curr* is the scheduling entity for the current task.

Note that the *vruntime* for the new entity is first initialised with the same value as the current task. This is significant, because the `entity_before` call is checking whether the *vruntime* of *curr* is less than the *vruntime* of *se*.

So the only way that condition will succeed is if the `place_entity` call sets the *vruntime* of *se* to something larger. So let's look at the [source](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.8/kernel/sched/fair.c#L1655) for that. The key bits are:

```
u64 vruntime = cfs_rq->min_vruntime;

if (initial && sched_feat(START_DEBIT))
        vruntime += sched_vslice(cfs_rq, se);

se->vruntime = max_vruntime(se->vruntime, vruntime);
```

So assuming the `START_DEBIT` feature is set (which [seems to be the case](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.8/kernel/sched/features.h#L12)), then the *vruntime* will be set to the run queue's *min_vruntime* plus whatever the `sched_vslice` call returns. If this is greater than the current *vruntime* then we're set - if not we'll be left with our initial *vruntime* value and the condition won't succeed.

I don't understand Linux scheduling well enough to say for sure, but I'm guessing that *min_vruntime* plus `sched_vslice` just isn't large enough most of the time.

I say most of the time because, when I was testing, I was able to get the child process to run first at least some of the time. So it's possible the `sched_child_runs_first` parameter does make a difference - it's just not a guarantee of anything.

The other possibility is that it's a bug in the code, and they should have started with the current task's *vruntime* rather than the run queue's *min_vruntime* when calculating the initial value in the `place_entity` function. That would have guaranteed the condition would succeed. But I suspect there's a reason for doing things the way they do which I just don't understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take some time to go through it.