# Does the Linux scheduler prefer to run child process after fork()?

Tags: linux, fork, scheduling

Does the Linux scheduler prefer to run the child process after `fork()` to the father process?

Usually, the forked process will execute `exec` of some kind so, it is better to let child process to run before father process(to prevent copy on write).

I assume that the child will execute `exec` as first operation after it will be created.

Is my assumption (that the scheduler will prefer child process) correct. If not, why? If yes, is there more reasons to run child first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote [The Linux Programming Interface (pg. 525)](http://books.google.de/books?id=2SAQAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA525&ots=qQpZ7bGyyy&dq=%22After%20a%20fork()%2C%20it%20is%20indeterminate%20which%20process%22&pg=PA525#v=onepage&q&f=false) for a general answer:

> After a `fork()`, it is indeterminate which process - the parent or the child - next has access to the CPU. (On a multiprocessor system, they may both simultaneously get access to a CPU.)

The book goes on about the differences in kernel versions and also mentions CFS / Linux 2.6.32:

> [...] since Linux 2.6.32, it is once more the parent that is, by default, run first after a `fork()`. This default can be changed by assigning a nonzero value to the Linux-specific `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first` file.

[This behaviour is still present with CFS](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.8/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5733) although there are [some concerns](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fa.linux.kernel/pgTyqRXWGJI/4xZF_LZvQpEJ) for the future of this feature. Looking at the CFS implementation, it [seems to schedule](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.8/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5758) the parent before the child.

The way to go for you would be to set `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first` to a non-zero value.

**Edit:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393268/1643939) analyzes the default behaviour and compares it to `sched_child_runs_first`.

Answer (score 3):

For the case where the child calls `exec` at the first opportunity you can use [`vfork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork) instead of fork. `vfork` suspends the parent until the child calls `_exit` or `exec`*. However, once it calls `exec` the child will be suspended if code has to be loaded from disk. In this case, the parent has a good chance to continue before the child does.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what about usual case. Will scheduler prefer child to father?

Comment: With vfork my reading is that the child is preferred, with fork, it is unspecified.