# What is the output of the following fork program?

Tags: c, fork

```
int main() {
int p1, p2;
printf("A\n"); // we always print A first
p1 = fork();

if (p1 == 0) { // child
    printf("B\n"); 

    p2 = fork(); // fork

    if (p2 == 0) {
        sleep(2);
        printf("C\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(0); // parent waits for child to finish
}
printf("D\n"); 
exit(0);


return 0;
}
```

The output I get is the following:

```
A // always first

B or D // whether we are in parent or child. Program may be terminated here

C // always since parent of p2 waits

D // since p2 parent exits if condition, prints D, then exits(0)
```

I've run this a 100 times and always I get `ABD ... terminate ... CD`. The 'D' always comes before the 'B'. Is this just random or is there a reason I am not seeing?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you always get ADBCD, or does the program sometimes terminate after the second letter? You seem to have posted contradictory information.

Comment: ABD ... terminate ... CD

Comment: See this answer especially the part under Fourth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697102/13422

Comment: Ah but then I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391201/does-proc-sys-kernel-sched-child-runs-first-work

Comment: The posted code has some significant oversights.  1) the necessary header file statements missing.  2) the returned type from a call to `fork()` is `pid_t`  not `int` 3) both calls to `fork()` are missing the check(s) for an error return.  4) the top level and second level parent processes fail to wait for the child process to exit. (such oversights result in zombie processes)  5) with so many processes, the call to `wait()` doesn't know jst who it is waiting for.  Strongly suggest using `waitpid()` (cont)

Comment: (cont) 6) the final line: `return 0;` will never be executed due to the preceding line contains `exit(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact output depends entirely on how the OS schedules each process.  There is no synchronization between the parent and the first child, so "B" and "D" may print in any order.

For example, on my machine I get "ADB (end) CD".